# How can I remove duplicate documents from CouchDB using python-couchDB and map reduce?

Tags: couchdb

I am doing python programming deal with the data stored in couchDB, but the data in the database have some duplication.
For example, these are two of the documents in a database which represent tweets:

```
{
  "_id": "0245d6a270ff7f2c9459544185adfc50",
  "_rev": "1-4a6ccb26cfde2da4b70188ba05d29c46",
  "twitter_id": "0d8e7f60615584747d869770b0033e55",
  "coordinates": null,
  "text": "Jimins playlist is sexy af"
}


{
  "_id": "0245d6a270ff7f2c9459544185ae03e5",
  "_rev": "1-4a6ccb26cfde2da4b70188ba05d29c46",
  "twitter_id": "0d8e7f60615584747d869770b0033e55",
  "coordinates": null,
  "text": "Jimins playlist is sexy af"
}
```

These document represent the same tweet, however there are thousands of document in the database. Can I remove the same tweets using map-reduce?

I use python as my programming language.

Comment: Do you want to _remove_ duplicate documents? map/reduce can't do that--it doesn't modify your data. Or do you just want to _ignore_ duplicate documents when doing a query? map/reduce can do that.

Comment: @Flimzy Could you please show me an example of how to ignore it, thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is probably not to create duplicate documents in the first place. Consider using the tweet ID as part of the doc ID to make this easy.